# How can I update a table based on results from a select query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I want to update table `course_main`. My initial query was:

```
update course_main
set data_src_pk1 = 2
where course_id LIKE '%FA2013' and available_ind = 'N'
```

Well this will get some courses(only a small set, fortunately)that I do not want to update. So I have a select statement to retrieve the actual data I do want to update, and it returns 145 rows.

```
select course_id from course_main
where course_id like '%FA2013' and available_ind = 'N'
and course_id <> 'ENGL-0330-112WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'ENGL-0360-112WE-FA2013' 
and course_id <> 'ENGL-0390-112WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'ARTC-1053-128HY-CEQ113'
and course_id <> 'ARTC-1353-128HY-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'HITT-1005-005IN-CEQ113'
and course_id <> 'HITT-1305-005IN-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'HITT-1305-006IN-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'READ-0300-104WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'READ-0340-104WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'READ-0370-104WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'WBCT-1003-011IN-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'WBCT-1005-011IN-CEQ113'
and course_id <> 'WBCT-1003-010IN-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'WBCT-1005-010IN-CEQ113'
and course_id <> 'ARTS-1301-012IN-FA2013'
order by course_id asc
```

I want to use an update statement to only hit the 145 results from the second query. Any pointers on how to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that `LIKE '%...'` cannot use an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update course_main
set data_src_pk1 = 2
where course_id in (select course_id from course_main
where course_id like '%FA2013' and available_ind = 'N'
and course_id <> 'ENGL-0330-112WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'ENGL-0360-112WE-FA2013' 
and course_id <> 'ENGL-0390-112WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'ARTC-1053-128HY-CEQ113'
and course_id <> 'ARTC-1353-128HY-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'HITT-1005-005IN-CEQ113'
and course_id <> 'HITT-1305-005IN-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'HITT-1305-006IN-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'READ-0300-104WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'READ-0340-104WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'READ-0370-104WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'WBCT-1003-011IN-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'WBCT-1005-011IN-CEQ113'
and course_id <> 'WBCT-1003-010IN-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'WBCT-1005-010IN-CEQ113'
and course_id <> 'ARTS-1301-012IN-FA2013')
```

?

Comment: This helps, thanks. I know I was "over complicating" it but this is what I was looking for, an example of the "WHERE IN" clause.

Comment: You don't need the sub select. This is complicated too. It can be further simplified as shown in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19405358/1243123)

Comment: i think he was looking for a way to update rows with the help of a key from a select. i further think his update was only meant as an example of his problem.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
UPDATE course_main
SET data_src_pk1 = 2
WHERE course_id LIKE '%FA2013' 
   AND available_ind = 'N'
   AND course_id NOT IN ('ENGL-0330-112WE-FA2013','ENGL-0360-112WE-FA2013',.....)
 ORDER BY course_id ASC;
```

?

Comment: This helps, thanks. I know I was "over complicating" it but this is what I was looking for, an example of the "WHERE IN" clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating this.

```
update course_main
set data_src_pk1 = 2
where course_id like '%FA2013' and available_ind = 'N'
and course_id <> 'ENGL-0330-112WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'ENGL-0360-112WE-FA2013' 
and course_id <> 'ENGL-0390-112WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'ARTC-1053-128HY-CEQ113'
and course_id <> 'ARTC-1353-128HY-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'HITT-1005-005IN-CEQ113'
and course_id <> 'HITT-1305-005IN-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'HITT-1305-006IN-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'READ-0300-104WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'READ-0340-104WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'READ-0370-104WE-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'WBCT-1003-011IN-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'WBCT-1005-011IN-CEQ113'
and course_id <> 'WBCT-1003-010IN-FA2013'
and course_id <> 'WBCT-1005-010IN-CEQ113'
and course_id <> 'ARTS-1301-012IN-FA2013'
```